# ImportError: Plotly express requires pandas to be installed

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

When I try to import plotly.express I get the error:

```
ImportError: Plotly express requires pandas to be installed.
```

The installation notes did not mention having to install anything additional. I can import plotly on its own, I only get the error when importing plotly.express. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you need to install pandas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas is a dependency that is only used in **plotly.express not in plotly**. For more you can visit this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2279).So you need to install pandas using `pip install pandas` or `conda install -c anaconda pandas`